# Create a ComboBox widget in Gtk2HS

Tags: haskell, combobox, gtk2hs

I want to create a ComboBox widget with this code:

```
void initGUI
  window <- windowNew

  ...

  cb <- comboBoxNewText
  comboBoxAppendText cb "Option 1"
  comboBoxAppendText cb "Option 2"
  comboBoxSetActive cb 0
  boxPackStart hb cb PackNatural 0

  ...
```

But this error appears:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’
                   with ‘text-1.2.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text’
    Expected type: ComboBoxText
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the second argument of ‘comboBoxAppendText’, namely
      ‘"Secuencial"’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: comboBoxAppendText cb "Secuencial"
    In the expression:
      do { void initGUI;
           window <- windowNew;
           set
             window
             [windowTitle := "A title",
              windowDefaultWidth := 1024, ....];
           vb <- vBoxNew False 7;
           .... }
```

I am just following this tutorial (http://www.muitovar.com/gtk2hs/chap4-2.html) and reading the docs (http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/gtk2hs-docs-0.9.12/Graphics-UI-Gtk-ModelView-ComboBox.html#v%3AcomboBoxInsertText)

**How can i make it work?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [documentation on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3). The documentation you linked is probably a decade stale by now.

[From that documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.14.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-MenuComboToolbar-ComboBox.html#t:ComboBoxText), we have

```
type ComboBoxText = Text
comboBoxAppendText :: ComboBoxClass self => self -> ComboBoxText -> IO Int
```

You are passing `"Option 1"` as the `ComboBoxText` argument. In vanilla Haskell, this is a `String` rather than a `Text` -- as the error says. You can either `pack` the `String`, as in

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
comboBoxAppendText cb (T.pack "Option 1")
```

or turn on `OverloadedStrings` to have this automatically done for `String` literals, as in:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
comboBoxAppendText cb "Option 1"
```

Comment: Now the compilation fail with this: Couldn't match type ‘T.Text’
                   with ‘text-1.2.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text’
    NB: ‘T.Text’
          is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal’ in package ‘text-1.2.2.2’
        ‘text-1.2.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text’
          is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal’ in package ‘text-1.2.2.0’
    Expected type: ComboBoxText
      Actual type: T.Text
    In the second argument of ‘comboBoxAppendText’, namely
      ‘(T.pack "Option 1")’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      comboBoxAppendText cb (T.pack "Option 1")

Comment: @Hamburguesa66 That sounds like you have built gtk2hs with version 1.2.2.0 of the `text` package but are building your executable with version 1.2.2.2. If you are building with ghc, use `ghc-pkg` to hide all but version 1.2.2.0; if you are building with cabal, try adding `--constraint text=1.2.2.0` to your `configure`, `install`, or `new-build` command.