# Get ComboBox widget value in Gtk2Hs

Tags: haskell, combobox, gtk2hs

I'm trying to get the ComboBox widget value with this code:

```
selectRadioB cb = do
ntxt <- comboBoxGetActiveText cb
case ntxt of
            Just ("Option 1") -> ...
            Just ("Option 2") -> ...
            Just ("Option 3") -> ... 
return ()
```

But, when i compile it, this error appears:

```
  Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’
                   with ‘text-1.2.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text’
    Expected type: ComboBoxText
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the pattern: "Option 1"
    In the pattern: Just ("Option 1")
    In a case alternative:
        Just ("Option 1") -> ...
```

How can i solve that? I've made a similay question ([Create a ComboBox widget in Gtk2HS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445882/create-a-combobox-widget-in-gtk2hs)), but i dont want to use the pack fuction.

Why i cant use fromString like this?

```
cb <- comboBoxNewText
comboBoxAppendText cb (fromString "Option 1")
comboBoxAppendText cb (fromString "Option 2")
comboBoxAppendText cb (fromString "Option 3")
comboBoxSetActive cb 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *can* use `fromString` like that. Why do you believe you can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-MenuComboToolbar-ComboBox.html#t:ComboBoxText), we see that `ComboBoxText` is a alias for `Text`:

> ```
> type ComboBoxText = Text
> ```

Now `Text` and `String` are both ways to represent text, but `Text` does this in a compact way, whereas `String` (which is actually an alias for `[Char]`) does this in a linked list approach (this consumes more memory and will usually result in less efficient processing).

## Using [`unpack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text-Lazy.html#v:unpack)

You can however simply use [`pack :: String -> Text` and `unpack :: Text -> String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#g:5) to convert between `String` and `Text`:

> **`pack :: String -> Text`**
>
> **`unpack :: Text -> String`**

So you could use:

```
selectRadioB cb = do
    ntxt <- comboBoxGetActiveText cb
    case fmap unpack ntxt of
            Just "Option 1" -> ...
            Just "Option 2" -> ...
            Just "Option 3" -> ... 
    return ()
```

## Work with [`OverloadedStrings`](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#overloadedstrings)

Nevertheless this is quite inefficient: you will first convert the `Text` to a `String`, and then Haskell will perform (usually) less efficient comparisons.

You can however use a language directive:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
```

that you can put at the head of your file. Now this means that if you write a string literal Haskell *can* interpret this as a `Text` element.

So if you write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

selectRadioB cb = do
    ntxt <- comboBoxGetActiveText cb
    case ntxt of
            Just "Option 1" -> ...
            Just "Option 2" -> ...
            Just "Option 3" -> ...
    return ()
```

Haskell will derive that `ntxt` has type `Maybe Text`, and thus that `"Option 1"` should be interpreted as a `Text` element.

If you use this syntax extension, you can also write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

-- ...

cb <- comboBoxNewText
comboBoxAppendText cb "Option 1"
comboBoxAppendText cb "Option 2"
comboBoxAppendText cb "Option 3"
comboBoxSetActive cb 0
```

So you can drop the `fromString` function.